# how can I add a addition feature into my Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, addition

I have a textfield in my firstViewContoller and thats where the user types in some numbers. Then in my secondViewController i have a label and in that label I want the number entered by the user to be shown. I have done till this but I dont know how I can take the value the user enters in the textfield every time and add it all up and show the result in the label. For example the user enters 5 so now the label is showing 5 then the user types in 20 and now i want the label to add that up and show 25 and keep on adding what the user enters.

//  ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
  @IBOutlet weak var amountSpent: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      amountSpent.delegate = self
      amountSpent.keyboardType = .numberPad    }
     private func amountSpent(_ amountSpent: UITextField, 

shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
         let invalidCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted
        
        return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invalidCharacters) == nil    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let resultViewController = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
        resultViewController.recievedInt = amountSpent.text!
    
}
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResult", sender: nil)  }    }
```

//  ResultViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ResultViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var totalAmount: UILabel!
    var recievedInt = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        totalAmount.text = recievedInt
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert the new and the existing values from string to Int and add them together before setting the label to the new total

```
class ResultViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var totalAmount: UILabel!
    var recievedInt = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let newValue = Int(recievedInt), let total = Int(totalAmount.text!) {
            let newTotal = newValue + total
            totalAmount.text = "\(newTotal)"
        }
    }
```

An alternative way to do it could be

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let newValue = Int(recievedInt) ?? 0 
    let total = Int(totalAmount.text!) ?? 0
    let newTotal = newValue + total
    totalAmount.text = "\(newTotal)"
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer but its not showing anything in the label.  I don't know if I did something wrong. I pasted your code into my ResultViewController. Should I have done something else?

Comment: @Mariam I have added an alternative solution in case there’s an issue with the initial values for the variables/abels

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a string variable to **store** the total value

   ```
    var totalValue = "0"
   ```
2. Add the below method to your project. This will add all your entered values and **will return the total value as a string**.

   ```
    private func getTotalCount(string: String) -> String {

      let strTotal = "\(totalCount) + \(string)"
      let arithmeticExpression = NSExpression(format: strTotal)
      let additionResult = arithmeticExpression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as! Int

      return String(additionResult)
    }
   ```
3. You will click the done/return button after you entered the count in the text field, **the delegate method will be triggered**. Call the **getTotalCount()** method inside the delegate method as below:

   ```
   func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

      totalCount = self.getTotalCount(string: textField.text ?? "0")

      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return true
   }
   ```

Thus adding new counts will be automatically handled inside the UITextField delegate method. You just need to pass the **totalValue** to the next View Controller like this:

```
    let resultViewController = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
    resultViewController.recievedInt = totalCount
```